# Blacklist IPs with iptables behind a Reverse Proxy

Tags: iptables, reverse-proxy, x-forwarded-for

I have a Ubuntu Server 16 and I use `iptables` as firewall. `HTTP` and `HTTPS` traffic is behind a Reverse Proxy that I cannot control, but I have `X-Forwarded-For` field activated.

Is it possible to filter out traffic at the `iptables` stage instead of adding rules in Apache?

If not what is the best way to implement black list in Apache?

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` is not able to inspect that deeply into packets. Even if it could, it would only be able to inspect HTTP traffic, not HTTPS. In apache, you can blacklist using the `Limit` directive.

Comment: `iptables` is limited to layer 2, is that correct?

Comment: From the TCP/IP network model layer 2 (Internet layer) you have the IP header, and can filter on things commonly in that, but iptables can also filter based on some details from the TCP/IP layer 3 (transport layer) details for some protocols like tcp/udp.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is quite possible, though it may require a kernel patch depending on your distrubution. There is the `string` netfilter extension that let's you match specific packets based on if a string is contained within them. We have used it in the past for handling DDOS traffic.

An untested example is here:

`# iptables -A INPUT -m string --string 'X-Forwarded-For: badIP' -j DROP`

Keep in mind that this is a rather blunt instrument and can result in traffic being unexpectedly dropped- make sure you craft your rules carefully and explicitly. As EEAA stated as well, it will not work on encrypted traffic.

More information is here: https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.18

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, but not suitable for my needs

Comment: How is it not suitable for your needs? It literally answers your question: `Is it possible to filter out traffic at the iptables stage instead of adding rules in Apache?`

Comment: Most of my traffic is HTTPS unfortunately

Comment: The link you provide me also explicitly discourage using it for this purpose, thank you anyway

Comment: Ah yes - if you are using HTTPS, you will have to do it where the HTTPS connection is terminated. 

The article only says don't use it for broad things like GET/POST (as they may be strings used in other messages) - using it for explicitly written blocks works very well.

Comment: Yes, I have learnt something useful with your answer, thank you

Comment: Just so others may know: I've had some problems applying this filter, and find out later that the headers where written in lowercase: 'x-forwarded-for'. you can search string with case insensitive option as well using the --icase option. (http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)